# Intermediate compute call before domain creation in DDD(Domain Driven Design)

Tags: api, domain-driven-design, ddd-service, dddd

I have a UI that takes visitor orders. After the visitor placing his order, UI has a button that calculates tax and gets back to the UI before placing the actual order.

I have **DDD based order API** with ADD, UPDATE, GET, GET ALL and DELETE endpoints. But for the intermediate "Get Tax" button what should I do? Is it a Query(CQRS) side operation or an API Endpoint that talks to different service classes to get the result before domain creation.

Answer (score 0):

If this calculation is *based on business logic* but does ***not require any persistent data*** to do it's job rather than the input you should simply put this logic into a domain service. That means, if the calculation itself is also not persisted.

You can also reuse this domain service at other places than in case you need it. Even as a parameter to an aggregate root's method.

So in your case I would ***simply call the domain service from the controller*** to perform the calculation. But make sure the domain services method will receive some value object placed in the domain layer as well as a method parameter (or just a primitive if that's enough) rather than any controller related objects (like request).